# Assigns min-width to a bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using one `panel panel-defaul` in my page to show some data but I need that the `min-width` of my panel be 720px if the Windows is resizing to less of 720px I need that appear a scrollX but the panel can´t be less of 720px like the use of `table-responsive` when I need to do something like that but using tables I do this:

```
HTML
<div class="example-table table-responsive">
    <table id="example-table" class="table table-hover">
    </table>
</div>

CSS
.example-table{
    max-width: 720px;
}
#example-table{
    min-width: 720px;
}
```

And if I use the rule `.panel{min-widht:720px;}` nothing happen.

**How can I get the same effect in my panel?**

**EDIT:** Ok I try this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvzy9s5k/) and my exact problema is that no matter that I set the `min-width: 760px` the content in the `panel-body` that is the two `col-sm-6` create two rows but I need that the two `col-sm-6` keep the same two columns and not pass to be two rows, at the first I think that was because the `min-weidth` but now I don´t know why this happen even when the scrollX is created.

Comment: `.panel{min-widht:720px;}` is mispelled; it should be `min-width` - would that be it?

Comment: that was my bad, I use `min-width` not `min-widht`, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your updated question, you want your columns to remain inline irrespective of screen width. You can do that by changing your `col-sm-6` to `col-xs-6` like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <strong>Something here</strong>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <strong>Something here</strong>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvzy9s5k/1/

Comment: Thank you I forgot this `.col-xs = *Extra small devices (ie Phones) (<768px)`.

Comment: Glad I could help!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `media-queries`like this:

```
@media (min-width: 720px) {
    .example-table {
        <!-- Your css properties here -->
    }

}
```

Comment: Still nothing, the panel got less of 720px

Comment: Please reproduce what you have done so far in jsfiddle.